# serve static assets in storybook monorepo

Tags: reactjs, storybook, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have a lerna + yarn workspaces monorepo which uses storybook.
Each package/component has its own /assets folder containing static images as following:

/packages 
         /component1 
                      /assets 
                            ... static images 
                index.tsx 
     /component2 
                      /assets 
                            ... static images 
                index.tsx

in the official documentation it says to include `-s` option but it suits only for a single general assets folder, not per package:
`start-storybook -p 6006 -s assets`

how can I serve those static assets in storybook **for each component**?

Answer (score 5):

You can specify multiple static directories if you split them via a `,` [as documented here](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/cli-options).

Plus you can also specify a path to serve it at if you split the source location and the path location with a `:`, undocumented, but you can have a look at [this split call in the source code here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/053394953320f7207d9a151d6597223d6b51ba67/lib/core/src/server/utils/static-files.ts).

Putting this together in this instance, you could run

```
"scripts" {
  "storybook": "start-storybook -s ./packages/component1/assets:assets,./packages/component2/assets:assets"
}
```

Comment: This was the answer I needed!  Undocumented or not, this worked great for me in 2021.

Comment: This worked for me which is supposed to be deprecated but adding staticDirs in main.js wouldn't

Answer (score 2):

well.. it seems that it is not supported out-of-the-box so this is my solution to the problem, hope it will help other people.

the basic idea is to copy all the static assets of all the packages into the storybook output directory:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    // build the storybook and run copy assets script
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -c .storybook -o .out && yarn copy-storybook-assets",
    // clean output directory, copy the assets to the output directory and run the storybook
    "dev": "yarn clean-storybook-output && yarn copy-storybook-assets && start-storybook -p 6006 -s .out",
    // clean the output directory
    "clean-storybook-output": "rimraf .out",
    // run on all the packages and copy all the static assets to the output directory
    "copy-storybook-assets": "copyfiles -f \"packages/**/assets/*\" -u 1 .out"
  },
```